# phone keypad does not open with focus() in javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init() {
  input.focus();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hola</h1>
    <input type="text" id="input" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> How can I make the keyboard open in the phone's browser? Try with focus() but it only appears blinking and the input is selected, but the keyboard does not open automatically, please, if someone knows how I can solve it, I would greatly appreciate it.